# Laravel at Shared Hosting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, npm, shared-hosting, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

After I successfully installed composer, npm and Tailwind in shared hosting, I am encountering this problem.
The page is being displayed but without css and js showing the error:

```
GET http://mydomain.preview-domain.com/css/app.css  net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://mydomain.preview-domain.com/js/app.js  net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

but in my `app.blade.php`  I'm importing:

```
<head> 
        ...
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
        ...
</head>
<body>
        ...
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        ...
</body>
```

It seems like the path to the public folder is wrong.
I would appreciate any help. I know that using Laravel in Shared Hosting is not a very good idea.

[NOTE]: I created a symbolic link from the website's public folder to the index.php of Laravel. This is how index.php runs.

Comment: can you please share website link

Comment: the website is not online. I'm using Hostinger. The preview of my website is http://home-and-style-gr.preview-domain.com/ .

Comment: are the app.css and app.js present in the website folder you uploaded to your website?

Comment: Only the index file is present in the website public folder which is the entry point. All the other files are in the Laravel default folders.